# Trying to create sortable list with functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Hi guys I'm trying to create a list of stocks for an automobile dealer to display their stock, I've been searching over the web for useful plugins but can't decide which direction to go for, javascript or php? Which plugin is popular for sorting list? Any recommendation is welcome.

Here are some basic requirements:

- Won't be a lot of items since it's for one dealer.
- Need functions like: Sort by Price (Highest to Lowest), Sort by KMs (Lowest to Highest), etc.
- Each list item will have many attributes, for a car it may have large amount of  categorised description, images, and video etc, so it might not be a good idea retrieving from database? Just my idea.

Under my circumstances, I don't know which one is the best option. I am a web designer, so I understand a little PHP and JS, but not enough for this project.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please refer to carsales.com.au or tradingpost.com.au for example. But lightweight with less functions needed...

Comment: You don't necessarily use plugins to sort. Both PHP and JS can sort. And asking what is best of PHP and JS is an opinion and dose not belong here.

Comment: @RoyW PHP runs on the server, and JavaScript runs on the client.  You will most likely need a combination of both in order to accomplish what you're trying.

Comment: @Anders I'm not asking which one is the best, I'm simply asking for a solution, I know I don't necessarily need plugin to sort, since my situation does not allow me to create such function I'm counting on plugins, AND I know both can sort, thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @watcher Yeah I thought so as well, the thing is I'm trying to find a suitable plugin to use, just wondering if you know any that you'd recommend? It's got to be somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to use JavaScript and i will explain.
Javascript is purely client side language which handles no data transfer and payload on server.
Javascript is not an object oriented language (PHP as well), which means you can insert entire different objects in any array / list cell.
Now, for your need : 
You can build a simple array in javascript and apply easy made functions to return sorted arrays.
For Example, a function that will sort your array by KM:

```
function sortKilometers ()
{
if (a.Kilometers > b.Kilometers) return 1;
if (a.Kilometers === b.Kilometers) return 0;
if (b.Kilometers > a.Kilometers) return -1;
}
```

function like this will just return a sorted array easily.
Pay attention, my code here can be incorrect, im too tired to simulate it, but most sort functions in javascript works this way.
PHP is working almost the same but javascripts counts as a lighter and more easy-to-use language.

hope that it was helpful :)

Comment: Thank you Ori, most contributing answer so far, and yes I figured it'd be JS since there ain't many items to display, which saves us from connecting to DB, I will try your method out, do you have any plugin in mind that can do the trick? Website is not built on any CMS btw.

Comment: aha, i found a great example : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp
Please read about javascript sort function containing a sorting method. you can define to sort it be anything you want. easy as that.
for example a.Km and b.KM instead of a < b. (a and b both represents a singular cell in the array)

Comment: Thanks mate appreciated your help